# Text containing special characters in command line cannot be well read

Tags: linux, command-line, ocaml

I have a function `analyze_text: string -> unit` to analyze a text. As a result, (most of the time,) `./analyze aText` launches the function with the argument.

```
let usage_msg = "./analyze [options] TEXT" in
Arg.parse options analyze_text usage_msg;
```

However, I realize that when the text contains special characters like `"`, `'` or `!`, it cannot be well read. Does anyone know if there is a way to well wrap the text and give it to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the shell there are many shell characters. You can escape the shell characters by enclosing your input in single quotes.

```
$ echo 'a*$b"$c"!d'
a*$b"$c"!d
```

If your input itself contains single quote. You'll have to enclose that in the double quotes and concatenate with the rest of substrings of input which are enclosed in single quotes.

e.g. You want to print: He$l!o Wo$r'ld
You can do it like:

```
$ echo 'He$l!o Wo$r'"'"'ld'
He$l!o Wo$r'ld
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the culprit is not your OCaml code, but the behavior of your shell, e.g., bash. When you enter text in the bash command line prompt many characters have special meaning, e.g., `"`, `'`, `$`, `\` and so on. To hush the special meaning of a character in bash you can either escape it with the backslash, e.g., `\$`, `\\`, `\'` or delimit with single quotes (but you will still need to escape single quotes in the single-quotes-delimited text.

The general approach is that when your input is actual text or data, not a sequence of commands and options, you should read the input from a file or from the standard input channel. This also helps, when the size of the input is large, as most of the shells limit (sometimes significantly) the total number of characters that can be passed through the command line. In vanilla OCaml, you can input the whole file into a single string using the following simple code

```
let read_file filename =
  let buf = Buffer.create 4096 in
  let chan = open_in filename in
  begin
    try while true do Buffer.add_channel buf chan 4096 done
    with End_of_file -> ()
  end;
  Buffer.contents buf
```

Then you don't need to deal with any special characters, as your input will be the file and no shell in between will do any interpretations. You can even analyze binary data with that.